# Model to deal with multiple observations (prediction)

Tags: regression, mixed-model, cross-validation, predictive-models, econometrics

I want to predict how much time it will take to go from a place to another on a given week day (Monday, Tuesday,...), in a given time of the day(morning/evening).

My data looks like this (of course this is just a simplification)
[image]

I have divided into train and test set.

As you can see, I got multiple observations for each route, so that I cannot run a linear regression because the assumption of independence of observations wouldn't be met.
What other model can I use to be able to predict my dependent variable (walking time)?

Thank you

Comment: I think you're confused about multiple observations for each route violating independence. A violation of independence would be if one walking time for one measurement directly influences another, even after controlling for the independent variables. I can't imagine any way this would happen as you've described it. Simply repeating the "experiment" doesn't cause problems.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen thank you for the help, very much appreciated really! However it is not clear to me why I don't have violation of independence as I have multiple observations of the same test subject (i.e. multiple obs for the same routes), as I am trying to predict walking time for each route (and I've got several observations for each route). Could you please explain further?  thank you very much

Comment: It's possible I've misunderstood, are you using the "route" as an independent variable in the model? Eg, Time = B0 + B1*Day + B2*Time + B3*IsRoute1 +B4*IsRoute2 +... Then you could predict the walking time of each route/day/time combination. If so, then there is no worry because you are controlling for the effect of different routes by including them as a covariate.  Or you could model Time = B0 + B1*Day + B2*Time, without the routes. Then you would be predicting the average walking time of all routes. In that case the independence assumption would be violated.

Comment: Note that the independence is an assumption about the residuals, or error terms. Not about the responses themselves.

Comment: This is extremely great news, thank you so so much!